# manage fragment appearance upon screen rotation in xamarin.android

Tags: xamarin.android, fragment, screen-rotation

after I thought that I finally finished my android app, I discovered that when my phone screen rotates, my application crashes. so after doing some research, I figured out that I have to add this line to my activities:

```
[Activity(Label = "FreeLineApp", Theme = "@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar", MainLauncher = true, NoHistory = true, ConfigurationChanges = Android.Content.PM.ConfigChanges.Orientation | Android.Content.PM.ConfigChanges.ScreenSize)]
```

this worked, but not completely. In fact, my app has a login fragment that appears once I launch the app. this fragment is displayed within a login activity that is set to be the main launcher with an empty layout. this login fragment doesn't appear totally when the phone screen is rotated. like it is cropped.
here is my login xml of the fragment:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:minHeight="1500px"
    android:minWidth="1000px"
   
    >
    <TextView
        android:text="Welcome to FreeLineApp!"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView1" 
    android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"/>
        <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:hint="Account"
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:background="@drawable/logincustom"
    android:layout_height="200px"
     android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>
     <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_height="200px"
    android:background="@drawable/logincustom"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="400px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:text="Login"
         android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/buttoncustom"
    />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:gravity="center">
<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox1"/>
        <TextView
            android:text="Keep me logged in"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView2" 
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/checkBox1"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        />
    
</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

and here is my login activity where the fragment appears:

```
 [Activity(Label = "FreeLineApp", Theme = "@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar", MainLauncher = true, NoHistory = true, ConfigurationChanges = Android.Content.PM.ConfigChanges.Orientation | Android.Content.PM.ConfigChanges.ScreenSize)]
    public class LoginActivity : AppCompatActivity,OnLoginInforCompleted
    {
        private AlertDialog _dialog;
        ISharedPreferences pref = Application.Context.GetSharedPreferences("UserInfo", FileCreationMode.Private);
        public void inputLoginInforCompleted(string userName, string passWord)
        {
            appuser app_user = new appuser()
            {

                UserName = user.Username,
                Password = user.Password
            };
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
            intent.PutExtra("User", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(app_user));
            this.StartActivity(intent);
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
            StartActivity(new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity)));
        }

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.layout1);
            //  StartActivity(typeof(MainActivity));
            var current = Connectivity.NetworkAccess;

            if (current == NetworkAccess.Internet)
            {
                string userName = pref.GetString("Username", String.Empty);
                string password = pref.GetString("Password", String.Empty);
                if (userName == String.Empty || password == String.Empty)
                {
                    MyDialogFragment dialogFragment = new MyDialogFragment();
                    dialogFragment.setOnLoginInforCompleted(this);

                    dialogFragment.Cancelable = false;
                    var SupportFragmentManager = this.FragmentManager;
                    dialogFragment.Show(SupportFragmentManager, "dialog");
                }

                else
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
                   
                    appuser app_user = new appuser()
                    {
                       
                        UserName = user.Username,
                        Password = user.Password
                    };

                    intent.PutExtra("User", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(app_user));
                    this.StartActivity(intent);
                }

            }
            else
            {
                

                AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

                alert.SetTitle("Connection failed");

                alert.SetMessage("Please, check your internet Connection!");
                alert.SetNeutralButton("okay", (senderAlert, args) => {

                    alert.Dispose();
                    MyDialogFragment dialogFragment = new MyDialogFragment();
                    dialogFragment.setOnLoginInforCompleted(this);

                    dialogFragment.Cancelable = false;
                    var SupportFragmentManager = this.FragmentManager;
                    dialogFragment.Show(SupportFragmentManager, "dialog");

                });
                _dialog = alert.Create();

                _dialog.Show();
            }
            // Create your application here
        }

       
    }
}
```

in the following images is what happens when the phone screen is rotated:
[image][image]

what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

You can create two layouts ,one is used for **Portrait**, and other is used for **Landscape**. Then when screen is rotated, it will show as your wants.

For example , the Layout folder is as follow:

[image]

And remove `ConfigurationChanges = Android.Content.PM.ConfigChanges.Orientation | Android.Content.PM.ConfigChanges.ScreenSize` from **Activity**.

Then the layout will changes when the phone screen is rotated.